# Open Source Equivalent to Humana Sans?

Tags: typography

Humana Sans is out of my price range for App licensing, I'm hoping to find something similar that's open source:

https://www.linotype.com/169295/itc-humana-sans-medium-product.html?licenseAvlType=4&format=ot-cff&branding=std

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The font you mention is ITC Humana Sans:

[image]

Of the free fonts I’ve skimmed through, [**Acme**](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/acme?filter%5Bclassifications%5D%5B0%5D=sans%20serif&filter%5Blicense%5D%5B0%5D=open&filter%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D=display) matches ITC Humana Sans the best. It’s a display font, but you may want to give it a try:

[image]

Acme was created by [Huerta Tipográfica](https://huertatipografica.com/en) in Argentina.
It is licensed under the [Open Font License](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL_web).